# Converting Tif to Jpg takes way too long

Tags: c#, jpeg, tiff

I'm trying to convert MANY (1000+) images from tiff to jpg, but after appr. 250-300 images it takes about 5-10 seconds for any further image, even though the first 250 took 20 seconds.

This is the code I use:

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(tifPath, "*.tif", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath).Save(jpgPath + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may save the files you received from Directory.GetFiles into a variable, so that the programm does not have to perform that search so many times

Comment: @HimBromBeere That is not the problem. The problem is that the memory is leaking due to undisposed resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image needs to be disposed or else it stays in memory:

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(tifPath, "*.tif", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    using (var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath))
    {
        image.Save(jpgPath + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

---

See this site for more information about using statements:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/using